# protobuf-net: properties versus fields

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

In our project, we have a data transfer object (DTO) class which is decorated with a `[ProtoContract]` attribute, and all of its members are public properties decorated with `[ProtoMember]` attributes - except that one of the members is a public field (by accident). Now we want to change the one public field into a property. Can this have an impact about the implicit protobuf contract? (We want to avoid breaking changes, and I suppose that this change is non-breaking, but I want to be sure.)

Comment: Your database and c# classes have to be compatible.  There is a mapping file that associates the database tables/columns with the c# classes.  Any changes to either the database or c# classes would require the updating of the mapping.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for the hint! Yet we don't work with a mapping file. Perhaps the term "DTO" was misleading here; all the mapping is done by hand, and the DTO is not directly backed by a database table.

Comment: A great tool to check things like this is to write a unit test. Create class A with a property, and Class B with a field of the same type, Serialize an A object and de-serialize to class B. It can also be useful to serialize your objects from some specific version, and write a test that ensures it can be de-serialized in your current version.

Comment: @JonasH thanks! In fact, I just checked and saw that your second suggestion is what we already have in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's absolutely fine; protobuf-net won't care, and the serialized payload will remain identical.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now that I know that all promises will be kept, I will sleep like a baby tonight :-)